# Sending Email using Sendgrid Fire and forget

Tags: asp.net, azure, sendgrid, azure-notificationhub

We're running an ASP.net MVC4.5 web app, and we have this api end point that does the following:

1. Send Email using SendGrid (normal sync code)
2. Send Notification using Azure Notification Services (normal sync code)
3. Trigger another endpoint in a 3rd party soap service (we're using azure storage queues here and a workrole, because the 3rd party endpoint is unpredictable and i might need to retry the call)

My question is, would it be an overkill to use azure storage queues for (1) and (2), I'm having second thoughts because, SendGrid for example, when sending an email using their SDK, I suspect that the email sending action happens instantaneously when im calling their email send endpoint, they are probably using some sort of queues as well and polling from it to send the messages.

This goes for the notification hubs for example, the message is added to their queues as well, so would it make sense to implement azure queues for those?